# Eclipse Zest for DOT plugin doesn't render shapes and colors

Tags: dot, eclipse-gef, graph-visualization, zest

I'm having a little trouble with the Eclipse Kepler zest2 plugin - it doesn't render the DOT graph's style and shape attributes at all. I mean, if I give a DOT graph to the plugin, it doesn't reflect the node colors and shapes, whereas if I run it through the graphviz application, it exports a beautiful image. Now I can't figure out if it's because I'm missing something in Eclipse, or is it a limitation from the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a limitation of the plugin - only some basic edge styles are supported, see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zest/DOT

Comment: Thanks, and that's why I'm switching to Gephi, seems to be more powerful (hopefully).